# Whole string in cell not splitting

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm running this code in vba and I would like the whole cell to get separated into an array in a new sheet but I cannot get it to split everything in the cell as pictured below. I would like for it to split in a new cell and a new array so I can search for key words in that array. Please take a look at the code and see what can be done.

Thanks

```css
Sub SplitWithFormat()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim i As Long, V As Variant


Set R = Range("d1", Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))
For Each C In R
    With C
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=True, comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, other:=False

        .Copy
        Range(.Offset(0, 1), Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
Next C
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub​
```

[image]

Comment: Try `split` with space as delimiter.

Comment: I would use split as well. You will need to double up though. You will split the cell into an array using vbCRLF as your delimiter, then split each array item using space as your delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell from your example if your cell is wrapped with a CR-LF or just a LF.

Assuming it's just a line feed this should work:

Replace this line

```
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=True, comma:=False, _
    Space:=True, other:=False
```

with this line

```
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=True, comma:=False, _
Space:=True, other:=True, Otherchar:=vbLf
```

If it actually is a combination of - then use this:

```
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=True, comma:=False, _
Space:=True, other:=True, Otherchar:=vbCrLf
```

> EDIT - convert split cells into array

Add new declarations at top

Dim varHorizArray   As Variant
Dim rge             As Range
Dim intCol          As Integer

Before `.Copy` command, add

```
Set rge = Selection
varHorizArray = rge
```

Example of using resulting array, add to bottom

```
    ' Array returned is two dimensional - 1 row by 7 columns
    For intCol = LBound(varHorizArray, 2) To UBound(varHorizArray, 2)
Debug.Print varHorizArray(1, intCol)
    Next intCol
```

Comment: Thanks that new line work. How would I change the offset to send the array to a new sheet so I can search the strings inside?

Comment: What array? I don't see anything in your code that references an array?

Comment: how can I make the split cells into an array?

Comment: Updated answer - should get you started

Comment: Thank you but it gives me a run time error '13' type mismatch after splitting the cells.

Comment: my apologies it was an error on my end. Thank you for the help.